# JQuery Problem With Lists

Tags: jquery, xhtml

Ok, here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .invirep{
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                var replylinkcode = $('<a href="#" id="reply"> [Reply]</a>');
                $('#comments ul li').append(replylinkcode);
                $('#reply').click(function(){
                    var textareacode = $("<br/><textarea cols='10' rows='2' id='replybox'></textarea>");
                    $(this).parent().append(textareacode);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="comments">
            <ul>
                <li>Comment 1</li>
                <li>Comment 2</li>
                <li>Comment 3</li>
                <li>Comment 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is:  why is it that it's only when I click the first item's reply link that the textbox appears and not for the other items (second, third and fourth items)?

Comment: click edit above to see real code, it's not rendering properly.

Comment: select all of the html and then click the { } button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using ID instead of class.

http://jsfiddle.net/a55Tb/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your appending a jQuery selector to an element.

```
var replylinkcode = $('<a href="#" id="reply"> [Reply]</a>');
```

should be:

```
var replylinkcode = '<a href="#" id="reply"> Reply</a>';
```

Comment: The jQuery function can be used to create new elements, so this is not the source of the problem - see: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using a *very old* version of jQuery - the current version is three major versions ahead. Please upgrade, there really isn't a lot of reasons not to.

Secondly, you're creating multiple elements with the same `id` - this is invalid HTML, and is probably the reason why the code does not work.

Using new syntax introduced in jQuery 1.4, you can rewrite the code as such:

```
$('<a>', {
    text: '[reply]', 
    href: '#', 
    click: function(){
        $("<br/><textarea cols='10' rows='2' id='replybox'></textarea>").appendTo(this.parentNode);
    }
}).appendTo('#comments li');
```